# Latex table: Increase column width

Tags: tables, overleaf, two-column

I created a table for some characteristic quantities.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Characteristic values}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcc}
\toprule
&Values\\
\midrule
EntryA&$A \sim 10$\\
EntryB&$B \sim 15$\\
Entry C, a lot of text\\Second line of text &$C \sim 19$\\
EntryD&$D \sim 10$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%
```

How can I manually increase the width of the left column as well as the space between each row? Secondly, It is possible to omit the top line?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Characteristic values}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\midrule
EntryA&$A \sim \num{10}$\\
EntryB&$B \sim \num{15}$\\
Entry C, a lot of text\\Second line of text &$C \sim \num{19}$\\
EntryD&$D \sim \num{10}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: By how much should the width of the first column be increased? About your second question: Is something stopping you from deleting the `\toprule` instruction? And, why do you specify the table to have three columns ("`lcc`") when there are only two columns to typeset?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the first table I create. I don't know - the longest line consists of 60 characters. The entries are too close to each other. Which commands could I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment, set the table's target width to, say, `0.6\textwidth`, and change the column type of the left-hand column from `l` to `X`. If `0.6\textwidth` is still too narrow for your taste, feel free to choose a larger target width (but, naturally, no more than `1\textwidth`).

If you don't want to print the line generated by `\toprule`, then just delete that instruction (or, if you prefer, comment it out).

The framelines at the edges of the following image are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded. Don't load this package in your real document.

If you want to increase the default spacing between rows, you issue an instruction such as `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`. (The default value of this parameter is `1`.)

[image]

A final comment: If you want the second and further lines of a cell to have hanging indentation, just change `X` to `>{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X`. (If you don't know what the preceding sentence means, just ignore it.)

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around text block (omit in real doc.)

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Characteristic values}

\medskip %insert some vertical whitespace
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{@{} X c @{}}
%%\toprule % <-- comment out (or just delete)
        & Values \\
\midrule
Entry A & $A \sim 10$ \\
Entry B & $B \sim 15$ \\
Entry C, a lot of text \newline 
Second line of text & $C \sim 19$ \\
Entry D & $D \sim 10$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your table can be written as `tblr` (defined in `tabularray` package) table:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Characteristic values}
\label{tab:?}
\begin{tblr}{width   = 0.5\textwidth,
             colspec = {X[l] Q[c, mode=math]},
             row{1}  = {mode=text}
             }
    \toprule % <-- comment out (or just delete), if you not like to have
            & Values        \\
    \midrule
Entry A     &   A \sim 10   \\
Entry B     &   B \sim 15   \\
{Entry C,\\ which has text in two or more lines} 
            &   C \sim 19   \\
Entry D     &   D \sim 10   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]